# Wcf service can't be lable to listen some times

Tags: wcf, exception

When my wpf app its running after a while

I'm get this error,

> There was no endpoint listening at "http://" that could accept the message.
>
> This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

My application can use the service but few times I got this error and my application hangs.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I'm guessing your service may have crashed, but I would need some more info to help you out

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I don't think, my service get crashed..because i got this error message, some times only..otherwise service can work with my application well. what may the reason for that?

Comment: Try handling the error so that your app doesn't hang. Then retry the call. If it continues to fail check your service is still available.

Comment: Thank u hugh. Is this exception because of service not available or else is there any reason?